# How to update URL parameters like trulia?

Tags: google-maps, url, parameters

I am working with property related website and want to implement same functionality like trulia having when we drag/move map, it will update URL with latitude, longitude and other parameters.

Is there any script behind on this?

e.g. http://www.trulia.com/sold/New_York,NY/11_zm/40.490415102406466,40.88455833289439,-74.51936504638672,-73.41867229736329_xy/1p_beds/2p_baths/30000-50000_price/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME,CONDO_type/map_v

Comment: You might want to look into using window.pushState() and replacing lng and lat in a url with coordinates of the center of the map when Google Maps drag event is fired.

Comment: @TimOsadchiy thanks for the hint I have found https://github.com/browserstate/history.js based on your answer